# Editing the Manifest.MF file with new plugin template wizard

Tags: eclipse, templates, plugins

I want to create a plugin template that includes a declarative service. so far, i have been following the lead of "[Creating your own Eclipse-plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-plugin-templates/index.html)", which works fine. 
Then I generate the OSGI-INF/my-component.xml file in the updateModel(..) method of the MyOptionTemplateSection, which also works perfectly.

..but then I need to add an additional line to the MANIFEST.MF file of the project that I want to create, and that's where I get stuck:

Service-Component: OSGI-INF/mycomponent.xml

How can I best achieve this?
I don't see any means of inserting this in the project's model prior to generating the bundle, and if I try to access the Manifest.MF file during the updateModel(..)  of my OptionTemplateSection, it isn't available yet. Before I start with executors and the likes, I was wondering if there is an elegant way to approach this; I don't think it is an unusual request, to be able to declare components in the template.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code that does this for the New Component Definition wizard is `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ds.ui.wizards.DSCreationOperation`, perhaps that can help.

Comment: Just the answer I needed! The additional functionality I need apparently needs to be assembled in a class that extends  org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation, which is then called by the performFinish(..) of the wizard. I will try to implement this tomorrow and report my findings. Thanks Greg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a day of following Greg's lead, I have found a solution that is not overly elegant, but comes close enough. If anyone ever wants to change the manifest.mf file, then one has to get PDE's IBundle interface. Sadly, access to this interface in discouraged by PDE , most likely because it is still under development (I have the feeling that the PDE team is phasing out the notion of 'plugin' in favour of 'bundle', which makes sense).

Anyhow, in the updateModel(...) method of your OptionTemplateSection -or the performFinish(..) method of your NewPluginTemplateWizard-  you get an IPluginModel, which is actually an IBundlePluginModelBase. The following three lines will  add a Service-Component to your manifest file:

```
@Override
    protected void updateModel(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
        IBundlePluginModelBase mb = (IBundlePluginModelBase) model;
        IBundle bundle = mb.getBundleModel().getBundle();
        bundle.setHeader( "Service-Component", "OSGI-INF/component.xml" );
                ....
        }
```

bundle.setHeader(key, value)  allows you to include *any* line to your manifest file, so you can also use this to create a fragment bundle, Web-Context or a custom manifest

As I said, this solution will produce 'discouraged acccess' warnings, but personally I think this an overly restricted choice of PDE, and not so much a matter of incorrect coding.